# Cross validation on fitted survival objects?

Tags: r, cross-validation, survival-analysis

I can see how cv.glm work with a glm object, but what about fitted survival models?

I have a bunch of models (Weibull, Gompertz, lognormal, etc). I want to assess the prediction error using cross validation. Which package/function can do this in R?

Comment: You should post some sample data and code.

Answer (score 1):

`SuperLearner` can do V-fold cross-validation for a large library of underlying machine learning algorithms, not sure that it includes survival models. Alternatively, take a look at the `cvTools` package, which is designed to help do cross-validation of any prediction algorithm you give it.